# PHP refuses update because in server root, Drupal 7 (php7.3) & Drupal 10 (PHP 8.1) on the same server both working - Can't update D10

Tags: php, composer-php, drupal-7

- PHP refuses update because it is in server root (no permission)

Drupal 7 (php7.3) & Drupal 10 (PHP 8.1) on the same server and both are working (although D10 is hamstrung by Composer not updating).

> Can't update (or install other modules) to D10 because Composer keep referring to server root Composer which requires update. . . Even when I call Composer from the D10 directory.

D10 IS running php8.1 (working) but won't update since Composer only sees root Composer (2.4.4) and "must" update to Composer 2.5.3 before allowing module installs.

D7 (working) but won't run (white screen no login) under PHP8.1. It returns to normal after setting php back to 7.3

Yes I assume there are D7 modules not compatible (with php8.1), but lots of (Drupal 7) modules and I have not found a fool-proof method or app to determine which ones are crashing Drupal7 under php8.

Of course I don't update D7 install with Composer.

Does anybody have an app to determine which Drupal 7 modules are compatible or not?

Thanks for your attn, Mike B

Done everything I know to do, but not wanting to destroy the Drupal7 install which is working fine.

---

I can't be the only one that needs my Drupal 7 install to become PHP8 compatible.
In any case my Drupal 10 install IS my dev site. I know, not suggested, but has worked with other Drupal upgrades.
I guess I don't know how to make the Drupal 10 install to "take over" the composer commands. I've tried from various (composer & others) folders in the Drupal 10 install but it still defaults to the server root.
I don't want the server root to default to php8 because it will crash the Drupal 7 live site.

---

https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/php-requirements-for-drupal-7
"(3) The latest Drupal 7 version is recommended to get full PHP 8 support." -March 2023
My Drupal 7 install ver is 7.98. Now I'm sure that some modules aren't compat, but just how to tell which ones is the rub. However, the Drupal 7 shouldn't crash if core is compat with php8. . .but it does. I naively believe that if my Drupal 7 install will be php8 compat then I will be able to update/add modules to my Drupal 10 install. (and maybe composer too)

Comment: "Does anybody have an app to determine which Drupal 7 modules are compatible or not" - to the best of my knowledge there is not an easy way to determine this in D7. In D8 and greater, the specific version such as D8.3 or D9.4 usually did a good job of identifying the PHP version, but D7 releases you might need to go to the individual automated tests area for each module (if it exists) and inspect. For the white screen, turn on full error-reporting and display to see the errors

Comment: "PHP refuses update" - what does that mean? Can you share the command you are running? Also, keep in mind that PHP 7.3 is pretty outdated

Comment: In cpanel terminal: it returns the same error (permission error) no matter which directory I make the command from. . ."composer self-update." Any composer command always defaults back the server root with a permission denial.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If there is any permission error, share the full and exact error message and the command you were using

Comment: a. Error: Composer update failed: "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" could not be written.  Rename (/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: a. "Error: Composer update failed: "/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer" could not be written.  Rename (/opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer): failed to open stream: Permission denied"   -----Can't "Rename," since root is the server. can't add modules to Drupal10 install since it needs updated Composer.  Can't run php8.1 on Drupal7 install (both Drupals on same server) because it goes blank/white screen (comes back to normal login after re-setting php back to 7.3)-------need to determine which D7 added modules (maybe 100) don't comply with php8.1.

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - why do you need to write to the Composer binary on your server to update your PHP application?

Comment: @MikeBurman: Cpanel might have lurked you in some corner here it does not support. I normally stay away from it. If the composer version is specifically important for a project or another, one road you can choose is to ship the phar file with your project and use that one for the command. Composer is always a single composer.phar file and then this won't interfere with any other composer version you have on that system. And do you have the projects under version control?

Comment: I've tried to call composer from the drupal 10 install directory, but it doesn't recognize it. It always defaults to the root composer with the error that it (composer) needs to update and that The D10 install needs PHP 8.1 to continue to function properly. All of which I know. I don't have cpanel root control, but server admin is responsive. However, I really don't know what to ask. D10 admin IS php8.1 and my live Drupal7 works under php7.3 but not php8.1. "If the composer version is specifically important for a project. . ." Drupal 10 can't do anything w/out it.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it. Why do you need to run Composer on that server in any way? Why not update your application on your development system and properly deploy it?

Comment: "I can't be the only one that needs my Drupal 7 install to become PHP8 compatible" - what do you mean by that? According to https://www.drupal.org/docs/getting-started/system-requirements/php-requirements, the first Drupal release to be compatible with PHP 8 is Drupal 9

Comment: `php composer.phar` is the invocation, that is `php` and then the path to `composer.phar`. system version will not be taken then.